# Is there a unix command to output time elapsed during a command?

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

I love using `time` to find out how long a command took to execute but when dealing with commands that execute sub-commands internally (and provide output that allows you to tell when each of those sub-commands start running) it would be really great to be able to tell after what number of seconds (or milliseconds) a specific sub-command started running.

When I say sub-command, really the only way to distinguish these from the outside is anything printed to standard out.

Really this seems like it should be an option to `time`.

Comment: There are commands that don't print anything. Also, a command might exist that outputs something, waits a bit, and outputs something more (`watch`, `tail -f`).

Comment: `time` is a command for measuring any executable, not only shell scripts. Output lines don't mean anything per se (as @choroba already noted). So `time` won't ever have such an option. It would be useless. This is a very specific case which makes sense for you, and for that specific script.

Answer (score 3):

> it would be really great to be able to tell after what number of
>   seconds (or milliseconds) a specific sub-command started running

One possibility is to use this `bash` variable:

> **SECONDS**
>
> This variable expands to the number of seconds since the shell was started.
>     Assignment to this variable resets the count to the value assigned, and
>     the expanded value becomes the value assigned plus the number of seconds
>     since the assignment.

To combine that with an output stream, consider this dedicated script which adds a timestamp to each input line:

```
$ cat timestamp-output
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  printf "%05d %s\n" $SECONDS "$line"
done
```

And pipe your script's output into that script.

```
$ your-script | timestamp-output
```

Example:

```
$ cat your-script
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
  echo "step $i started";
  sleep $(($RANDOM%10));
done

$ your-script | timestamp-output
```

Output:

> 00000 step 1 started
>    00002 step 2 started
>    00010 step 3 started
>    00015 step 4 started

---

This could be refined to timestamp only the output lines that signal the start of a sub-command, assuming they can be grep'ed:

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="^start of command"
while read line
do
 if [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]]; then
   printf "%05d %s\n" $SECONDS "$line"
 else
   echo "$line"
 fi
done
```

Sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
  echo "start of command: $i";
  echo some output
  echo other output
  sleep $(($RANDOM%10));
done
```

Sample output:

```
00000 start of command: 1
some output
other output
00002 start of command: 2
some output
other output
00006 start of command: 3
some output
other output
00008 start of command: 4
some output
other output
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find out when child processes start running, you can use `strace -f -tt` and analyze the output, or potentially roll your own script to do that for you.